# Fundamental solution of Poisson equation in the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: analysis, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, laplacian

If we consider the Poisson's equation
$$
-\Delta u=f(x), \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
we can construct the fundamental solution
$$
u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of the Laplace's equation. Now consider the problem
$$
-\Delta_{\mathbb{H}^2}u=f(x), \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ \mathbb{H}^2,
$$
where $\mathbb{H}^2$ is the Hyperbolic Plane and $\Delta_{\mathbb{H}^2}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Can we obtain a same type of integral representation to the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at Stoll's lectures 
*[Harmonic function theory on real hyperbolic space](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuivuuq6XMAhUkIsAKHSbJAaoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.561.4447%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNHGXW3XAJaaCrX_zT8AhUpHS2uWAQ&sig2=mRzLpwfRa5S7Abacs2YxEw)*

where he constructs the Green function, or at Jaming's article "Harmonic functions on the real hyperbolic ball I" Colloquium Mathematicum vol 80 No 1 (1999) 63-82