# What's the exact expression of Green's function on poincare disk?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, greens-function

Consider the Poincare disk $\mathbb{H}^2$, that is the unit disk endowed with the following metric
$$
g_{ij}=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}\delta_{ij}.
$$
I believe there exists a global Green's function on $\mathbb{H}^2$ (is that true?), i.e., a function $G$ satisfying
$$
-\Delta_{\mathbb{H}^2}G(x,y)=\delta_x(y).
$$
My question is, what's the exact expression of such $G$?

If we take $x=0$. In Euclidean case, we know $G(y)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log |x|$. So I guess in the Hyperbolic case, $G$ should be $G=-\frac{1}{a}\log d(0,x)$, where $d(0,x)=\log \frac{1+|x|}{1-|x|}$ is the geodesic distance and $a$ is the measure of unit geodesic ball in $\mathbb{H}^2$.

But I didn't find any useful reference.

Am I right, or is there any reference paper that is related to this topic?

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966245/fundamental-solution-of-poisson-equation-in-the-hyperbolic-plane

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks a lot. From this reference I know the fundamental solution for Laplacian on poincare disk is totally same as the one in Euclidean space. Thanks!